# about running an application which requires admin privileges on a locked down user account

Tags: c#, windows-services, manifest

I have a Winforms app which runs under a standard user account (i.e. user account logs in, app runs under that named user). However, this very app needs to perform some actions (Writing to registry being one of them), which require admin privileges, and restart a service (the problem I want to avoid is this one: [Service Controller not able to start service - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490772/service-controller-not-able-to-start-service-access-denied)).

One way to solve this is to make the entire app run as administrator, using a manifest file. Alternatively, would it work if I write a windows service (call it x) running under the highest power account (local system I believe), which can do all of the high-power-account-required stuff and, which in turn calls the existant service, which I need to manipulate and is running under the named/logged-in user account (thus a standard user). If so, how can I invoke a windows service to run on demand (or would a console app be better)?

Comment: Would spawning a process from your app which runs a batch script (which you could dynamically build) do the trick?

Comment: Possibly. I was actually thinking of creating a process object which could execute a console app under certain credentials (similar idea really).

Comment: Where are you writing to? I believe writing to HKCU is allowed for current user regardless of admin rights, but HKLM and HKCR are restricted to admin and system.

Comment: You can try starting this process object with `yourObject.Start.Verb="runas"` (iirc), but your users may get UAC prompts I think. Would that matter?

Comment: Oh never mind, the registry part isn't your problem

Comment: @sasfrog, unfortunately yes. Perhaps I can make a process object and give it a username/password of an admin account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in this instance:

For the service use this tool to allow your limited account group or user permissions to start/stop: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en
And a bit on how to use:
http://ss64.com/nt/subinacl.html

As for registry, you need to find the appropriate registry key > right-click > permissions > "Full Control" for the "Users" group or the name of the specific "limited" group that need these tweaked permissions.

I typically run this all from an script in an installer or from setup script. The script adjusts the permissions for the very specific things that are necessary, registry/services/files/folders. This allows the software to run under the context of the limited rights user, not elevated with admin rights.

As a working example I use this for a custom OpenVPN implementation I built that runs for non-admin users. I had to allow them start/stop the service and write to the log file (in the program files folder).

If you need a more hands on working example, let me know and I can probably throw something together.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an admin task helper process, (Second Executable) that runs as administrator via manifest file.

Then your normal app can be run under the limited user, but when you want to execute admin tasks, you fire up your helper process via `Process` class. Windows should prompt for elevation (to administrator) JUST to perform the tasks you want to.

Comment: Hey look, you posted a comment saying pretty much this as I posted my answer.

Comment: Would there be a way to bypass/hide the login box? I think a windows service may be good in this way.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, a silent windows service may be the way to go. The end user won't have knowledge of an admin-based account. So if I have the layer of indirection in my service, I hope that works. OR make a process object, execute it etc, and set the account details to that of a relevant account.

Comment: @dotnetdev: No. If you could, it would defeat the whole purpose of UAC, which is to prevent applications doing things they shouldn't without the user's permission.

Comment: I see. one last thing - what about executing a process (Via the c# object) and setting the username to an admin username?

Comment: If you were running as an admin with UAC on, it'll just prompt for elevation. IF your user doesn't have permissions, you need to provide one that does. This is the point of UAC, if you're running into a problem with UAC it usually means the way you're going about something probably isn't the right way, or you genuinely need to be and admin to use the program. This is why UAC was brought into existence, mainly to curb poor design & protect a system from intrusion via unprivileged users.